# How to install only the YugaByte client programs

Tags: database, yugabytedb

How to install only the YugaByte client programs like cqlsh, ysqlsh, csv loaders, jdbc driver etc without the server stuff?

It seems that the installation instructions cover only the server side installation: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently working on a separate cli and dev-tools installer. In the meanwhile, you can do the following.

**Command line shells**

You can get the cli's by downloading the server side package itself, untar it and you should find most of the cli's in the `bin` directory.

For example, something like the following should get you the cli's:

```
$ tar zxvf yugabyte-2.0.8.0-darwin.tar.gz

$ cd yugabyte-2.0.8.0/

$ ls bin/ysqlsh bin/cqlsh
bin/cqlsh   bin/ysqlsh
```

**CSV loaders**

- For YSQL, you can just use the `COPY` command in `ysqlsh` to import data.
- For YCQL, you can download the loader/unloader from here: https://github.com/yugabyte/cassandra-loader/releases

**JDBC drivers**

- You can just use any PostgreSQL 11.2 driver, since it is fully compatible.
- Here is the YugabyteDB JDBC driver where we are building cluster awareness: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yugabyte/ysql